# can't debug django app in VS Code with docker database: 'could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known'

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My django app is connecting to a postgreSQL database that runs in a docker container.

I can connect to this container no problem if I run the app manually on my local machine:

`./src/manage.py runserver`

However, if I try to run a debug configuration through VS Code, I get this error:

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

The `db` container is there though, and `docker logs db` return info for it

Here is the code the VSCode is running when I try to debug (I did not set any of these settings):

```
/home/me/Developer/myproject/venv/bin/python /home/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 37153 /home/me/Developer/myproject/src/manage.py runserver --noreload
```

How can I get my debug configuration to work?  Here's the configuration that VSCode generated:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver",
        "--noreload"
    ],
    "django": true
},
```

EDIT: The `db` container is run with `docker-compose up db`
Here's my **docker-compose.yml** (i've removed redis, celery, and beat services for simplicity).  I am only running the `db` container in docker, not the web service:

```
version: '2' # supported by default install on Ubuntu 18.04

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine # Production server is using 9.5.17
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: . # current directory
    env_file: .env
    command: bash -c "python /app/src/manage.py migrate && 
                      python /app/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

There's also a **docker-compose.override.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

**.env**

```
POSTGRES_HOST=db
```

Comment: How are you running your containers, `docker-compose`? You need to post your compose file if so because this sounds related to the docker setup.

Comment: added docker-compose stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think that this version of your docker compose file does not support what you want. Change your docker version to 3.7 as below:

```
version: '3.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't debug inside docker container like this in VS code. For that, you need run the VS Code from inside of the containers. To do that, you can follow these steps:

### First Step: Having Appropriate Docker Environment

Well, if you have a Dockerfile or a docker-compose.yml file, thats super cool. If you don’t have it, thats fine too. In that case, you can use an Docker Image to build the docker environment. FYI, if you are using Alpine Based Docker environment, then you need to use VS Code Insiders Edition.

### Second Step: Creating `.devcontainer` Folder

In this step, you need to create a new folder named .devcontainer inside your source directory. Inside that, create a `devcontainer.json` file.

### Third Step: Configuring devcontainer.json

If you are using docker-compose, then you can use the following code:

```
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  "context": "..",
  "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml"], // You need to point it your `docker-compose.yml` file with proper path.
  // Uncomment the next line if you want to publish any ports.
  "appPort": 8000,

  // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created.
  // "postCreateCommand": "python --version",
  "service": "web", // You must define which service you are going to use from docker compose.
  "workspaceFolder": "/app", // path to your source inside docker file
  "extensions": [
    // extensions which is going to be installed inside the docker environment
    "ms-python.python",
    
  ],
  "settings": {
    // additional settings for VS Code configurations
    // You can copy paste them from `settings.json` of your workspace
    // Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
  }
}
```

### Fourth Step: Installing Remote Development Extension Pack

Install [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) Extension Pack from VS Code Market, or use VS Code’s integrated market to install it:

### Final Step: Run VS Code from Container

After installing, an icon will appear at bottom left of your VS Code:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ruddra.com](https://ruddra.com/content/images/2019/08/vscode-remote-icon.png))</sub>

Now, click on that, and few options will appear like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruddra.com](https://ruddra.com/content/images/2019/08/vscode-remote-click.png))</sub>

Now click on `Remote-Containers: Reopen Folder` in Container option, the VS Code will reload. Now, you are inside the Docker Environment!!

You can also create a debugger and put break points in source code to see if it hits any.

More information can be found in the [**`official documentation`**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) or you can checkout this [**`blog`**](https://ruddra.com/posts/vscode-remote-docker-development/) as well.

---

unless you are inside the docker container, the error `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known` will not be resolved. Still if you intend to debug in your local machine, then you can take the advantage of your environment variable like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '...',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('db_name'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('user'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('password'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('host'),
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

You need to make sure that you have a postgresql running in local machine or expose the database docker ports to access it.

Comment: I appreciate the detail instructions (I actually want to be able to do this!) however, that's not my problem in the question.  I am only running the db service in a container.  I want to debug the django project OUTSIDE of a container, just like I can do with `./src/manage.py runserver` which has no problem connecting to the db service.

Comment: @43Tesseracts please see the updated section of the answer

Comment: Thank you. I know the db container is running properly and ports are exposed, and my settings.py is already correct because I can connect to it no problem by running my app with just `./manage.py runserver`  for some reason the debug configuration is not running it the same way, but I don't understand what the debug configuration is doing differently that is causing the problem.

Comment: debug configuration will run in your local machine, not inside container

Comment: But why doesn't that work when I can run my app on my local machine without any problems?

Comment: Ok, I'm trying the development in a container, which seems to be running ok.  However, when I "Re-open folder in container" it runs the web service in the background, so I can't see the output like I do when I `manage.py runserver` myself locally.  Also, because the web port is already in use, running a debug configuration fails also.  I try to stop the web service (using containers list on the left) but it just restarts itself. haha.  I know I can change the debug port, but how do I stop the container from running the web service?

Comment: I think now you can debug in vscode quite easily, I have a django app setup with cookie-cutter, then I follow this to setup on vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose. After running docker, just go to run, attach